# jquery promise not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

The then function isn't firing after loading this XML file.  I'm not getting any errors and I can see the file loading in the network tab.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
$.when(
    $.get("data/data.xml", {}, function (file) {
        xml = file;
    })
).then(function(){ 
    console.log("Loaded");
});
```

Comment: well, you need to add a fail call to detect errors. check out the example [here](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/).

Comment: No you don't @garglblarg [*Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved, **rejected**, or still in progress.*](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/)

Comment: Where is `xml` declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to user jQuery recommended call back functions as [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).

> The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callback
>   methods are removed as of jQuery 3.0. **You can use jqXHR.done(),
>   jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead**.

In your case you can use `done()` or `always()`.

If you want to execute on success.

```
$.get("data/data.xml", {}, function (file) {
        xml = file;
} ).success( function(){ 
    console.log("Loaded");
} );
```

If you want to execute on no matter of success or error.

```
$.get("data/data.xml", {}, function (file) {
        xml = file;
} ).always( function(){ 
    console.log("Loaded");
} );
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case, why use `$.when` at all, the `get` method returns a promise (or deferred), so you should be able to chain `then` on that method directly

```
$.get('data/data.xml', {}, function (file) {
    xml = file;
}).then(function(){ 
    console.log('Loaded');
});
```

Comment: Nice.  I was reusing some old code I'd written to load multiple files.  Didn't realise you could chain `then` onto `get`.

Answer (score -1):

In this case it was because the xml was malformed.  It looks like if the xml is loaded but can't be parsed, the $.get callback isn't fired but no error is thrown.